# What C standard does XC16 v1.5 use by default?

Tags: pic, mplab, xc16, compiler-version

I can't find a clear answer to what C standard Microchip's XC16 v1.5 compiler use by default (xc16-gcc -> options = empty).

We clearly get a different result if we specify it to `-std=C99`, but from what?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xc16 compiler uses the C89 standard.
Have a look a chapter 7 in the [manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB%20XC16%20C%20Compiler%20Users%20Guide%20DS50002071H.pdf).

> This compiler conforms to the ANSI X3.159-1989 Standard for programming languages. This is commonly called the C89 Standard. It is referred to as the ANSI C Standard in this manual. Some features from the later standard C99 are also supported.

With the XC8 2.0 compiler and up selected, you can enable the C99 standard.